# bash how to declare arrays from text file

Tags: arrays, bash, text, text-files

my script is

```
#!/bin/bash
readConf(){

$1 is the variable you are looking for

rconf=`grep -v "#" ./hold.conf | grep -F $1`;
rconf=${rconf#*'='}; 
}

readConf 'path'; pth=$rconf;

echo $pth;
```

and this is my text file:

```
path=( "/classic.hold" "/score.hold" )
```

the code will output `( "/classic.hold" "/score.hold" )`

the `rconf` variable will give me what is after the = sign,so i want to know how to make bash read this as a array declaration instead of normal text

Comment: If you are calling the function to get one variable at a time, why do you need an array?  It is not clear if you want the function to read all the variables from the file into an array.  In that case, you need an associative array.

Comment: thank you very much,i edit my code and put `readConf 'path'; 
declare -a pth=$rconf;` and it worked